# Passenger "Web application could not be started" exit (SystemExit) with foreman-installer

Tags: ruby, passenger, puppet, theforeman

I installed puppet-master 3.4 foreman1.6 and phusion passenger with the official Foreman-Installer on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

But if a puppet-client trys to connect to my running master it get an exception. Due to passenger what could not be startet, with following message:

```
Web application could not be started

exit (SystemExit)
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:492:in `exit'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:492:in `rescue in exit_on_fail'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:478:in `exit_on_fail'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/application.rb:362:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:137:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:91:in `execute'
config.ru:37:in `block in <main>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Installed is: ruby 1.9.1, ruby-rack, ruby-rake, ruby-passenger

I can't figure out the problem. Normally it should work immediately after the Foreman-installer installation.

Anyone an idea ? I'm a really puppet Greenhorn so be gently.;)

As answer to sumid :

No not really, for puppet it is Port 8140. Here my netstat -a table:

> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address
>   State tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           *:*
>   LISTEN tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*
>   LISTEN tcp        0      0 localhost:59581         *:*
>   LISTEN tcp        0      0 *:3389                  *:*
>   LISTEN tcp        0      0 localhost:3350          *:*
>   LISTEN tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*
>   LISTEN tcp        0     64 ubuntutest.infraser:ssh 172.17.75.185:62878
>   ESTABLISHED tcp6       0      0 localhost:ipp           [::]:*
>   LISTEN tcp6       0      0 localhost:postgresql    [::]:*
>   LISTEN tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*
>   LISTEN tcp6       0      0 [::]:8140               [::]:*
>   LISTEN tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*
>   LISTEN tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*
>   LISTEN tcp6       1      0 localhost:44927         localhost:ipp
>   CLOSE_WAIT udp        0      0 *:ipp                   *:* udp
>   0      0 *:38570                 *:* udp        0      0
>   ubuntutest.infraser:ntp *:* udp        0      0 localhost:ntp
>   *:* udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:* udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:* udp6       0      0 localhost:47575
>   localhost:47575         ESTABLISHED udp6       0      0 [::]:51315
>   [::]:* udp6       0      0 fe80::250:56ff:fe9a:ntp [::]:* udp6       0
>   0 localhost:ntp           [::]:* udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp
>   [::]:* udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*

Comment: The Puppet master will log to syslog when it fails to start up, usually because it's trying to change permissions on something and can't.  Try `grep puppet-master /var/log/syslog` to get more details.

Comment: thanks but in syslog is no log with puppet-master or similar. And the `/var/log/puppet/masterhttp.log` is empty too. O.o

Comment: Isn't something using the web app port already? 3000 if I recall correctly.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. However, when I manually start puppet master with `puppet master --daemonize` and then kill it, subsequent puppet agent runs work fine behind passenger/nginx.